# Render in action is shown on the screen - Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new programming in ruby ​​on rails and I need help with a problem of a `render` in an action of my controller

This is my action:

```
def events_calendar
  render json: {events: all_events}, status: :ok
end
```

This is what it shows me:

[image]

I want you to show me my web page and not the data of my render, how could I solve this?

Comment: I want to send the JSON of all events to the url so that in js get them by means of a get and manipulate them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [respond_to](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.3/classes/ActionController/MimeResponds.html#method-i-respond_to).

```rb
def events_calendar
  respond.to do |f|
   f.html
   f.js { render json: {events: all_events}, status: :ok }
  end
end
```

That way, you get the JSON when you call `events_calendar` using AJAX, and still render `events_calendar.html.erb` when you use a plain HTTP resquest.